# Ruby on Rails gem 'byebug' installing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

[image: here is error for 'byebug' installing.]

How can I fix this error? This issue is created when I check the rails version in a demo created website using this command.

Comment: Well, output gives you some hints, doesn't is?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/9)

Comment: In *Ubuntu 16.04*, one site that helped me was `http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#ubuntu___debian` needed to install `zlib1g-dev` and `liblzma-dev`. `sqlite3` was another snag. Had to uninstall `sqlite3` in Ubuntu and install the rubygems.org sqlite3 gem instead.

Comment: This could help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751824/how-do-i-install-byebug-for-ruby-on-windows

Answer (score 3):

you can also use another debugger gem 'pry', '0.9.12.6' and remove gem 'byebug' .

Then run bundle install

Comment: May I know why my point has down I just provide another way and it is not wrong?

Comment: I upvoted you. I commented out the byebug gem in the Gemfile, reran bundler and no errors. Its not critical to get a Rails app running, only used for debugging. Would like to try byebug on windows sometime if it ever gets working.

Comment: I didn't down vote this but perhaps it was down voted because you didn't answer the question? suggestions like yours are valid comments, but as it doesn't give the user any insight into the problem he or she is confronting, it's not a valid answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The output in yellow is asking you to run `bundle install` instead of `gem install`

You should do that.

**Update:**

It looks like the windows version build is failing. Only passes for ruby 2.0.0 but not for above versions.

You can check the status at [byebug's github project](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) and the [windows build status](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/deivid-rodriguez/byebug)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is set to treat warnings as errors. You can compile the extension manually after switching off -Werror in the Makefile. If that works, you must register the gem also manually like so:

```
gem spec [something like Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0]/cache/byebug-5.0.0.gem --ruby > \
[something like Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0]/specifications/byebug-5.0.0.gemspec
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the build (it's [passing in the released version](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/build/234), and in any case, it's not failing at compile time).

It might or might not be problem in byebug (I think it's more likely something with your Ruby / DevKit installation though), but it's not manifested in the CI build for sure.

That being said, the error can certainly be solved by just removing the gem from the Gemfile and running `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem for ruby version 2.1.7 and after some reading this is how i solved it . I just replaced gem 'byebug' with gem 'pry' and it just worked like magic !

Answer (score 0):

I solved this reinstalling my devkit in windows.

First I went to mi devkit folder and i wrike

```
ruby dk.rb init 
ruby dk.rb review
ruby dk.rb install -f
```

One line by one. Finally try again

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue for past few hours.
Then, I updated the Ruby version from Ruby2.2.6 to Ruby 2.3.3 and updated the devkit too.
It worked! :-)