# Need help installing byebug on my computer

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm just a newbie at ruby and currently using Windows 7 as my operating system. I have been trying to install the ruby gem byebug with no success.  I've installed and uninstalled ruby a number of times hoping to correct the problem but each time I do I get the same error.... Namely:

```
D:\>gem install byebug
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing byebug:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: D:/Ruby23x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.5/ext/by
ebug
D:/Ruby23x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160617-3564-1jtff0p.rb extconf.rb
D:/Ruby23x64/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Ruby23x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-
9.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Ruby23x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/
byebug-9.0.5/gem_make.out
```

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried this http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/ ?

Comment: My best suggestion is: Install a virtual machine with Linux (Debian, Ubuntu... anything you like) and use Linux to Ruby development. Windows will always be a problem for you.

Comment: Read this too: http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2016/06/rails-on-windows.html

Comment: And this: http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2016/06/building-native-extensions-for-ruby-gems.html

Answer (score 1):

Being new to this I mistakenly entered this first as a comment. While going through a number of posts I found a solution to my problem of installing byebug.
I first uninstalled my original attempt at installing it and then re-installed it with the following entry:

gem install byebug --platform=ruby --verbose

This same method worked for installing the gem json which also caused an installation a problem.  I hope this helps someone else who is having a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has been number or reported issues with installing `byebug` with windows.

Since I'm not on windows I personally cannot verify these fixes. But all of them suggest to uninstall the devkit and force install it.

Have a look at these issues/solutions

1 https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/119

2 [SO questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050258/ruby-on-rails-gem-byebug-installing-error)

Comment: While going through some of the posts I've seem to have found a solution the one I posted.  I first uninstalled my first attempt at installing byebug and re-installed it with the following entry: gem install byebug --platform=ruby --verbose .  This same entry also worked for installing the json gem... I hope this helps someone who is having the same problem

Comment: @dannyc1943, I believe you can accept your own answer , so that next person find it easier to locate it :)